# Unable to connect to local CouchDB with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, couchdb

I am trying to send POST requests to my database using the jquery.couch.js jQuery plugin that comes with CouchDB. I am unable to connect to my database in any way and have been testing using the following script:

```
$.couch.urlPrefix = 'http://localhost:5984';
    $.couch.info({
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Using Firebug on Firefox, I am able to see the following error:

> "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://localhost:5984/"

I also get the following warnings:

> 1. Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5984/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
> 2. Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5984/. (Reason: CORS request failed).

Comment: try the instructions for running the test, minus running the test: https://github.com/apache/couchdb-jquery-couch

Answer (score 0):

My solution ended up being very simple. CouchDB doesn't come with CORS enabled by default, so you must enable it manually. I found the script [add-cors-to-couch](https://github.com/pouchdb/add-cors-to-couchdb) which will enable this for you.

```
npm install -g add-cors-to-couchdb
add-cors-to-couchdb
```